# htaccess with different parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to add a parameter in my url through the .htaccess file. I have 5 parameters,3 int,1 float (for example 3.5) and a string.

With 4 parameters, without the string, it works well; but if I try to add the fifth parameter, the get variable of this takes the decimal part of the fourth parameter(the float).

I don't understand why. This is the htaccess row with 4 parameters:

```
RewriteRule sedi/([0-9]+)/ripetizioni/filtra/([0-9]+)&([0-9]+)&([0-9](.[0-9])?)$ tutor.php?id=$1&p=$2&z=$3&v=$4 [L]
```

Instead,when I add the fifth parameter,the line becomes:

```
RewriteRule sedi/([0-9]+)/ripetizioni/filtra/([0-9]+)&([0-9]+)&([0-9](.[0-9])?)&([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ tutor.php?id=$1&p=$2&z=$3&v=$4&search=$5 [L]
```

Example,if search was "mathematics" and v was `3.5`, the url takes correctly,but the get variable of search takes `.5`

Comment: Why are you splitting your float up in 2 variables?

Comment: @jeroen the float variable is not split up. It could be a single variable,with an optional decimal part.

Comment: As you are using parenthesis, you are capturing the value if it is there in the fifth parameter. You should use non-capturing parenthesis or just `[.\d]` for the whole number.

Comment: @jeroen like the suggestion of hjpotter92 below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following rule instead:

```
RewriteRule sedi/(\d+)/ripetizioni/filtra/(\d+)&(\d+)&([.\d]+)&([a-z\d]+)$ tutor.php?id=$1&p=$2&z=$3&v=$4&search=$5 [NC,L]
```

The behaviour you are experiencing is exactly because of the reason mentioned by jskindle in [the other answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/29882425/1190388).

Comment: I'll try your suggestion. Thanks for the moment.

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteRule sedi/([0-9]+)       - 1
/ripetizioni/filtra/([0-9]+)&   - 2
([0-9]+)&                       - 3
([0-9](.[0-9])?)&               - 4/5
([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$                - 6
 tutor.php?id=$1&p=$2&z=$3&v=$4&search=$5 [L]
```

I guess wrong 5th element place. However, if you need 5th element with dot, you need apply: \. (slash dot, to escape dot symbol) rule

**Edit:**

You have 5th element inside 4th, so your 5th element you want is 6th, so try this:

```
([0-9](\.[0-9])?)&               - 4/5
tutor.php?id=$1&p=$2&z=$3&v=$4&search=$6 [L]
```

Comment: I don't understand where is the difference with my rule. The fourth element is a single float variable. So,the element with dot is the fourth,not the fifth. How the rule become with the slash?